# How to create a Standards Compliant Intermediate SSL Certificate

Tags: ssl, tomcat, https, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have a certificate chain comprised of the root certificate, intermediate certificate, and server certificate. The root certificate is installed on my local machine. The intermediate certificate and server certificate are installed on my tomcat server.

I am unable to find instructions anywhere on how to create an intermediate certificate such that it is standards compliant. This is the error that I am receiving:
[image: Chrome Certificate Error]

Here are the details of the "inter" certificate, according to [KeyStore Explorer](https://keystore-explorer.org/):
[image: KeyStore Explorer Certificate Details]

Comment: This is not about programming or development, but it depends on which standard(s) some unidentified program or system is applying. _On the Internet_ (which is not the only place X.509 certs are used) RFC5280 says MUST AKI, SKI, KU with keyCertSign, and BC with cA=true; CABforum BR (as of 1.7.6) (re)lists all those except SKI, and adds Policies with OID, and CRLDP, and SHOULD AIA with caIssuers. All/any extensions in turn require v3. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/249347/what-differentiates-a-ca-cert-from-a-server-cert and more links there.

Comment: Do you really need intermediate certificate? Do you have any idea what is this?